# not being able to set up android dev environment.not able to open sdk manager

Tags: android

I am not able to open the sdk manager.I have downloaded the latest sdk and tried using jdk 7 and 8 and also tried editing the .bat file but a small command prompt appears and its gone..!! kindly help me..!! the errors are

```
[2014-05-14 10:01:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path  
specified.


[2014-05-14 10:01:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'xcopy' is not recognized as an  
internal          or external command,


[2014-05-14 10:01:14 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the guidelines I've created while making my system up for Android. And felt like making clear cut instructions for any newbies will help in the future with the below clear notes...Follow them...

- Author : Ramakrishna Balla
- Android Installation Guidelines

  1. Install the latest JDK available from www.oracle.com on to your PC in to C drive on to the below location : C:\Program
     Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
  2. Set the path in your system : • Select Computer from start menu -> system properties -> advanced system settings -> under advanced tab
     -> environment variables -> new and setup like below : • Variable Name : JAVA_HOME and Path is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
  3. Visit : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and download the latest ADT Bundle • Note 1: Download it through either IE or
     FireFox. Use DownloadAcceleratorPlus (DAP) if required from CNET •
     Note 2: Downloading it through Chrome results in Error as of now (25
     Mar' 2-14). So, please prefer either IE or FireFox. For more details
     visit this page :
  4. Extract it to the home and follow as instructed • In my case, I've downloaded to C:\Users\balla\AndroidDevelopmentTools\ • Extracted it
     to
     C:\Users\balla\AndroidDevelopmentTools\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundlewindows-
     x86-20131030
  5. Also download ADT Plugin 'ADT-22.6.0.zip' or 'available latest' from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
     to the folder C:\Users\balla\AndroidDevelopmentTools
  6. Start the Eclipse from C:\Users\balla\AndroidDevelopmentTools\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundlewindows-
     x86-20131030\eclipse
  7. Select the workspace when eclipse begins  • In my case it is :
     C:\Users\balla\AndroidDevelopmentAndHandsOn\
  8. Eclipse asks for the SDK Location preference • Point it to the SDK stored location. In my case it is :
     C:\Users\balla\AndroidDevelopmentTools\adtbundle-
     windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030
  9. In Eclipse -> • Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software. • Click Add, in the top-right corner. • In the Add
     Repository dialog, click Archive. • Select the downloaded
     ADT-22.6.0.zip file and click OK. • Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name
     and click OK. • In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox
     next to Developer Tools and click Next. • In the next window, you'll
     see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next. • Read and
     accept the license agreements, then click Finish. • If you get a
     security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the
     software can't be established, click OK. • When the installation
     completes, restart Eclipse.
  10. Open SDK Manager from the Eclipse tool. Use the Icon indicated and begin installing the required packages. That's it. • Note : Do
      NOT have any spaces in your directory or folder names when creating a
      workspace for android usage
  11. You Are DONE
- Key Notes to Remember :

  - Ensure to keep updating SDK Manager and Eclipse regularly. Ensure to have Internet working before taking this
    step as it searches online for updates.
- For Eclipse, : Go to Help
  --> Check for Updates --> It automatically updates online • For SDK Manager : Go to SDK Manager. In my case, it is :C:\Users\balla\AndroidDevelopmentTools\adt-bundlewindows-
  x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\ and Click on the
  SDKManager icon.
- Sometimes, it is preferred to close the Eclipse while updating the SDKs., so please do close the Eclipse before
  taking this step.
- Check for updates available and accept the license terms and Install them.
- Once completed the installation of SDKs, start the Eclipse again.
- You are ready to Go !
- All The Very
  Best !!!

Comment: Please double check your path and If still error persists, please post what exactly you've followed and where you've downloaded each of them. Do mention including the paths you downloaded/installed. As the error is purely related to the Path...your clear details help us resolve the issue

Comment: The error is the same when i try to open the sdk manager..!!downloaded adt bundle and jdk in C:\Users\SATISH\Downloads.the sdk extracted and placed in C:\Program Files\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.the jdk is installed in C:\Program Files\Java

Comment: The path is set to PATH : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add environment variable "Path", something like below (for reference)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of extracting ADT Bundle to the C:\Program Files....please extract it to the same folder where you've downloaded.
- In your case Download the ADT Bundle to C:\Users\Satish\Downloads\android....here the bundle
- Also extract the ADT Bundle to the same folder C:\Users\Satish\Downloads\android...here the extraction.

Are you able to start the Eclipse in first place ? Have you kept the preferences in Eclipse already ?

Comment: I am able to start eclipse

Comment: the problem persists even after extracting in the downloads folder